# Escaping an unicode string using backslash notation in c#

Tags: c#, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

how i can convert this word

> mamá

to this word

> mam\U00E1

Comment: It's not "converting", it is escaping.

Comment: What is the rule for deciding which character to escape? I mean, why not escape them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like the code below.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
string word = "mamá";
foreach (char c in word)
{
    if (' ' <= c && c <= '~')
    {
        sb.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("\\U{0:X4}", (int)c);
    }
}
string escapedWord = sb.ToString();
```

Or in a more compact way:

```
Func<char, string> escapeIfNecessary = c => (' ' <= c && c <= '~') ? c.ToString() : string.Format("\\U{0:X4}", (int)c);
escapedWord = string.Join("", word.Select(escapeIfNecessary).ToArray());
```